# What to do with an invalid close reason?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, closed-questions, close-reasons

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904807/lyx-breaking-long-formula-lines) question is currently in the reopen queue, as it was noted that it's not a duplicate. However it's still off-topic and should either be closed anyway or migrated to TeX SE site. I'm not sure how to vote. There are many related questions about changing the close reason, however I am unable to find the answer to the following question:

Should I vote to reopen the question and hope it gets closed for the new reason (or migrated), or should I leave it closed as it still doesn't fit SO guidelines?

Comment: Yes, I saw this also. The top voted answer is identical to the duplicate and the accepted answer is two links to other SO questions... let it be.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Thanks, that resolves this particular case, but what to do in general? For example, if a question was closed as duplicate, but then gets edited so it's not a duplicate any more, but becomes off-topic for whatever reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just reopened it since it's not an exact duplicate.  I'd migrate it if it weren't too old. (Questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated.)  LaTeX questions used to be on-topic on Stack Overflow, so we have a lot of them that pre-date the LaTeX site that are still open and will remain that way.

In the general case, if a question is closed for completely the wrong reason, but should still be closed, go ahead and flag it for a moderator and explain what needs to be done.

Comment: Thanks! I'll remember to do that.